# Bridging is breaking the server: KVM configuration

Tags: networking, ip, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I'm pretty new to networking and just can't get my head around this.

I'm trying to setup KVM-Qemu so I can run some virtual machines. The instructions I'm following are telling me to use eth0 and eth1 as local and WAN connections. I only have eth0 which is used for WAN. I created (or tried to) eth1 and the appropriate bridging, but this keeps disconnecting me from the server when I restart the network interfaces.

Any idea how I can fix this, as I only have eth0?

The instructions are here:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/kvm-virtualization-in-redhat-centos-scientific-linux-6/

For the bridging, I'm using the settings that my host has provided me with for the additional IP.

Starting eth0 configuration:

```
##Note for customers who want to create bridged networking for virtualisation:
##Gateway is set in separate file
##Do not forget to change interface in file route-eth0 and rename this file
device: eth0
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
HWADDR=50:46:5d:xx:xx:xx
IPADDR=144.76.xx.xxx
NETMASK=255.255.255.255
SCOPE="peer 144.76.yy.yyy"
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6ADDR=2a01:4f8:191:7282::2/64 
IPV6_DEFAULTGW=fe80::1
IPV6_DEFAULTDEV=eth0
```

At this point eth1 doesn't exist (though instructions say it should).

Then I create eth1 from instructions:

```
DEVICE=eth1
ONBOOT=yes
HWADDR=00:30:48:C6:0A:D9
BRIDGE=br1
```

Then I add the bridges:

```
DEVICE=br0
TYPE=Bridge
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
## setup LAN/VLAN ips as per your needs ##
IPADDR=10.10.29.66
NETMASK=255.255.255.192
DELAY=0

DEVICE=br1
TYPE=Bridge
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
## setup INTERNET ips as per your needs ##
IPADDR=74.ww.xx.yy
NETMASK=255.255.255.248
GATEWAY=74.ww.xx.yy
DELAY=0
```

(I replace the bridge specific settings with those that my host has provided for br1)

Then I restart the network and it fails.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: Please edit your question to specify exactly what your configuration was and how you changed it.

Comment: Done! :) I initially didn't run it in screen, which is why it was not coming online again, but I have no idea why it's not working anymore. Do you have any links to somewhere I can learn more about this possibly?

Comment: So you only have one NIC, not two, as the guide suggests. This means you can't have two, local and WAN networks, and you only need to use one NIC as the WAN network link, skipping the entire LAN thing. Do you have multiple public IPs available for the WAN? Are they all in the same subnet?

Comment: I have 3 IPs in total. At the moment, the main IP is on eth0 the rest are on eth0:0 and eth0:1 respectively. Two are using the same subnet, one is using a different one. 255.255.255.224/248
Do you think I could still set it up like this?

Answer (score 0):

Something looks fishy with the ipv6 binding. ipv6 networking must be bond using the statement NETWORKING_IP6=yes and the host name must be entered. For more information I found the tutorial at https://wikis.uit.tufts.edu/confluence/display/TUSKpub/Configure+Pair+Bonding,+VLANs,+and+Bridges+for+KVM+Hypervisor